# Chrome failed to start: crashed in Selenium testing

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using C# Selenium for automated testing, and after the most recent chromedriver update 89.0.4389.2300, Google chrome starts and crashes right away. The weirdest thing is that when I am running it on my local, everything works fine, but I am also using Azure pipelines to run my tests on a server. The server one gives me this:

**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)**

I have googled around and tried things like adding chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox") and chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-dev-shm-usage") but nothing helps. Chrome on my server is updated to the correct version too. The tests run headless.

Anyone else is having this issue?

Comment: seee if the chromedriver you are using is compatible with the browser version

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions that chromedriver could not bind to open debug port on running Chrome.

Possible cases I met with:

- old version of Chrome browser or chromedriver - since some version the port has changed
- wrong Chrome binary location (chromedriver is looking for ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe***)